# Hive Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I have an EMR Setup, which is supposed to come with Hive and Hadoop pre-configured.

As far, as I can see for any command which require MapReduce Job, Hive fails.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

So, I went to Job Tracking URL, and here is the relevant output:

```
Diagnostics: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.isLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:690)
...
```

Any help with this error would be appreciated...

Stack Trace points to codes:

[org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/org/apache/hadoop/net/NetUtils.java)

[Network Interface Definition](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/net/NetworkInterface.java#NetworkInterface)

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact stacktrace when trying to run a datanode. The IPv4 address of the `eth0` interface was forward-resolvable in DNS, but it wasn't reverse-resolvable (i.e. I could resolve the hostname to its IP but the reverse lookup of IP to the corresponding hostname didn't work). The datanode started as expected once the PTR record pointing from IP to hostname got created.