# oozie - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

While running the oozie sample examples, Oozie jobs are getting scheduled and status showing as Running. After some times jobs get KILLED. While digging the hadoop logs found these exceptions.

I have setup the oozie 4.3.1 with Hadoop 2.7.3. I have also updated the job.properties with proper nameNode and jobTracker configurations.

Please let me know the whats needed to changes and to fix the issue.

[Oozie Web Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dsSU.jpg)

```
            User:   root
            Name:   oozie:launcher:T=java:W=java-main-wf:A=java-node:ID=0000000-191231120255907-oozie-root-W
            Application Type:   MAPREDUCE
            Application Tags:   
            YarnApplicationState:   FAILED
            Queue:  default
            FinalStatus Reported by AM: FAILED
            Started:    Tue Dec 31 12:04:15 +0530 2019
            Elapsed:    2mins, 0sec
            Tracking URL:   History
            Diagnostics:    
            Application application_1576228338940_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
            For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://f091403isdpbato05:8088/cluster/app/application_1576228338940_0013Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
            Diagnostics: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
            Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

[Hadoop Application Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRM7q.jpg)

yarn-root-nodemanager-load-5.log

```
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,264 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001 by user root
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app application_1576228338940_0013
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=root IP=10.32.193.39 OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1576228338940_0013    CONTAINERID=container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1576228338940_0013 transitioned from NEW to INITING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Adding container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001 to application application_1576228338940_0013
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationImpl: Application application_1576228338940_0013 transitioned from INITING to RUNNING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,268 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1576228338940_0013
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/examples/apps/java-main/lib/oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.3.1.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/oozie-hadoop-utils-hadoop-2-4.3.1.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1576228338940_0013/job.splitmetainfo transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1576228338940_0013/job.split transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/root/.staging/job_1576228338940_0013/job.xml transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,269 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Downloading public rsrc:{ hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/examples/apps/java-main/lib/oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar, 1577773923766, FILE, null }
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Downloading public rsrc:{ hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.3.1.jar, 1577773807011, FILE, null }
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,288 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Downloading public rsrc:{ hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/oozie-hadoop-utils-hadoop-2-4.3.1.jar, 1577773807007, FILE, null }
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,297 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Downloading public rsrc:{ hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/json-simple-1.1.jar, 1577773807004, FILE, null }
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to download resource { { hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/examples/apps/java-main/lib/oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar, 1577773923766, FILE, null },pending,[(container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001)],14920685961731101,DOWNLOADING}
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
            at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.isLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:691)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.isLocalAddress(DFSClient.java:1079)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.<init>(RemoteBlockReader2.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:441)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:818)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:697)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:355)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:656)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:882)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:934)
            at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:366)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:267)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,304 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/examples/apps/java-main/lib/oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar(->/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/filecache/106/oozie-examples-4.3.1.jar) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to FAILED
            2019-12-31 12:04:45,306 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to download resource { { hdfs://10.32.193.39:9000/user/root/share/lib/lib_20191231120005/oozie/oozie-sharelib-oozie-4.3.1.jar, 1577773807011, FILE, null },pending,[(container_1576228338940_0013_01_000001)],14920685961866685,DOWNLOADING}
            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
            at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.isLocalAddress(NetUtils.java:691)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.isLocalAddress(DFSClient.java:1079)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.<init>(RemoteBlockReader2.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:441)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:818)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:697)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:355)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:656)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:882)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:934)
            at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:85)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:59)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:119)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:366)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:267)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
            at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

yarn-root-resourcemanager-load-5.log

```
            appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 with final state: FAILED, and exit status: -1000
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 State change from LAUNCHED to FINAL_SAVING
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService: Unregistering app attempt : appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.AMRMTokenSecretManager: Application finished, removing password for appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAttemptImpl: appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: The number of failed attempts is 2. The max attempts is 2
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,456 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Updating application application_1576228338940_0013 with final state: FAILED
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1576228338940_0013 State change from ACCEPTED to FINAL_SAVING
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating info for app: application_1576228338940_0013
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Application Attempt appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 is done. finalState=FAILED
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: Application application_1576228338940_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
            For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://f091403isdpbato05:8088/cluster/app/application_1576228338940_0013Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
            Diagnostics: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
            Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: application_1576228338940_0013 State change from FINAL_SAVING to FAILED
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.AppSchedulingInfo: Application application_1576228338940_0013 requests cleared
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAuditLogger: USER=root OPERATION=Application Finished - Failed TARGET=RMAppManager RESULT=FAILURE  DESCRIPTION=App failed with state: FAILED   PERMISSIONS=Application application_1576228338940_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1576228338940_0013_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
            For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://f091403isdpbato05:8088/cluster/app/application_1576228338940_0013Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
            Diagnostics: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
            Failing this attempt. Failing the application.  APPID=application_1576228338940_0013
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.LeafQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1576228338940_0013 user: root queue: default #user-pending-applications: 0 #user-active-applications: 0 #queue-pending-applications: 0 #queue-active-applications: 0
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.ParentQueue: Application removed - appId: application_1576228338940_0013 user: root leaf-queue of parent: root #applications: 0
            2019-12-31 12:06:15,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMAppManager$ApplicationSummary: appId=application_1576228338940_0013,name=oozie:launcher:T\=java:W\=java-main-wf:A\=java-node:ID\=0000000-191231120255907-oozie-root-W,user=root,queue=default,state=FAILED,trackingUrl=http://f091403isdpbato05:8088/cluster/app/application_1576228338940_0013,appMasterHost=N/A,startTime=1577774055215,finishTime=1577774175456,finalStatus=FAILED,memorySeconds=58978,vcoreSeconds=28,preemptedAMContainers=0,preemptedNonAMContainers=0,preemptedResources=<memory:0\, vCores:0>,applicationType=MAPREDUCE
```

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is probably misleading, `Could not` **`initialize`** `class` **`java.net.NetworkInterface`** smells of a tricky network configuration issue -- cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780985/hive-could-not-initialize-class-java-net-networkinterface for instance

Comment: Bump the Log4J logging level to `DEBUG` for YARN containers to get some insights about which kind of "network interface" fails, and on which address _(public DNS entry? Kubernetes private DNS entry? local "/etc/hosts" entry? public IP address? private IP managed by an hypervisor? etc etc)_